# Ignore route in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, iis-10

I'm trying to let my Angular code call APIs.

It looks to me like the Angular code 'catches' my calls to the API. How can I instruct the Angular app to 'pass on' the requests to web applications in IIS?

I deploy the Angular app to a web site at the root, say www.dummy.com.
I have an identity server running as web application at www.dummy.com/IDP and
the single API to call at www.dummy.com/API.

If the relative route starts with IDP or API, I want the respective web applications to handle them.

How can I do that?

I've tried to wrap my head around URL Rewrite and ARR on IIS, but would prefer a solution in code.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: 'travel-expenses', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent},
{path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent},
{path: 'signin-redirect-callback', component: SigninRedirectCallbackComponent},
{path: 'signout-redirect-callback', component: SignoutRedirectCallbackComponent},
{path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent},
{
    path: 'travel-expenses',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/travel-expenses/travel-expenses.module').then(m => m.TravelExpensesModule),
    canActivate: [UserSignedInGuard]
},
{path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
```

];

Comment: How are you making the requests? What makes you think Angular is catching them? What's responsible for the routing?

Comment: Rel routes in angular:  api/  and idp/. Relative routes in api:  ../idp/

Comment: jonrsharpe: I hit the angular app through a request to the web root. Displays nicely. Then tries to log in using IDP. It works locally using localhost and different ports but not on server. IDP has a webpage, but navigating to www.dummy.com/IDP shows app page and 404. I've added snippet with routes,

Comment: can you share your server config , how you deployed angular app ?. i guess it's related to server ,  if you open this ww.dummy.com/IDP directly in browser and then redirect to angular app , then i guess need to add some point in server , for this endpoint do some custom things

Comment: Leandro, sorry, that was long ago ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [angular proxy-config](https://angular.io/guide/build#rewrite-the-url-path) option. This lets you reroute api calls as needed, and call it during run or build, e.g. `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

example config file (proxy.conf.json):

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "https://the-api-server.com",
        "secure": false,
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks much like what I was looking for. Thanks! But it does look like it's an option for development server? Is this also for use on app deployed to e.g. IIS?

Comment: Yes, the example is for a development server. If you want to use the config file while deployed, you would update the `angular.json` file, search for `"serve"`, and under options, add `"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.config.json"`

Comment: Ah! Cool! But this (example) would redirect https://the-api-server.com/api to https://the-api-server.com? My problem is that I actually want to hit https://the-api-server.com/api but can't get past https://the-api-server.com?

Comment: remove the "pathRewrite" portion and you're good. Have a look at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy (look for devServer.proxy) for all the options

Comment: actually, a bigger list of all the options are at: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-options